# Alamofire multiple parameters (Query and Form) Swift 4

Tags: swift, alamofire

I'm having a problem sending a POST request with Alamofire.
I need to send the usser and password fields as application/x-www-form-urlencode and also some query data in the url.

I am creating a URLRequest to handle the process, but I'm getting always a 400 response from the server, so I guess the problem must be in the way I create the request.

This is the example in Postman:
I need to send a param in the url and two more in as application/x-www-form-urlencode

[Postman 1 - Parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJs1n.png)
[Postman 2 - ContentType](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sbZdR.png)

I need to do this (that i have in Android)

```
@FormUrlEncoded
    @POST(Constants.AUTH_LDAP)
    Call<ResponseBody> authLdap(
            @Query(value = Constants.PARAM_REQ, encoded = true) String req,
            @Field(Constants.PARAM_LOGIN) String login,
            @Field(Constants.PARAM_PASSWORD) String password
    );
```

And this is what I have in swift

```
let queryParamters  =  [Constants.Params.PARAM_REQ:req]
let headers = ["Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"]
let fieldParameters = [
    Constants.Params.PARAM_LOGIN : user,
    Constants.Params.PARAM_PASSWORD : pass]

let url = URL(string: Constants.EndPoints.AUTH_LDAP)
let request = URLRequest(url: url!)
let encoding = try URLEncoding.default.encode(request, with: queryParamters as Parameters)
let encodingpa = try URLEncoding.httpBody.encode(request, with: fieldParameters as Parameters)
var urlRequest = encodingpa
urlRequest.url = encoding.url
urlRequest.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers
Alamofire.request(urlRequest).responseData(completionHandler: { response in
        switch response.result {
            case .success:
            print("sucess")
            print(response.response)
            case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
        }
    })
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: do you need post request with query String ?

Comment: Do you mean doing something like: `let encodingpa = try URLEncoding.queryString.encode(request, with: fieldParameters as Parameters)`

Answer (score 1):

Try to create url from queryParameters using URLComponents like

```
var urlComponents = URLComponents(string: Constants.EndPoints.AUTH_LDAP)!
urlComponents.queryItems = [
  URLQueryItem(name: Constants.Params.PARAM_REQ, value: req)
]

let headers = ["Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"]
var request = URLRequest(url: urlComponents.url!)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
request.httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: fieldParameters)
request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers

Alamofire.request(request).responseJSON { response in

}
```